# Change Width of Object on Screen Resize

Tags: javascript, css, object-tag

How do I use Javascript to change the width of an object when the screen is resized to a smaller width? **When the screen is resized back to the bigger size, I want the bigger object.**

Comment: use relative sizing, e.g. `75%`

Comment: Exactly how do I do that? Excuse me for my questions, I just started using Javascript.

Comment: I mean in your CSS. Set the width to `75%` or some other percentage. This isn't something to use JavaScript for

Comment: I get what you mean.

Comment: Please include some code for reference. HTML for a start let us know what we are working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle an object size in a responsive screen is through a relative size on css, like vihan1086 said. This could be made like this:

```
<div style="width: 75%">My Content</div>
```

This would make this element fill 75% of the screen, no matter the size of the screen.

If you really want to do that in JS, you could do something like this with the help of jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var window_width = $(window).width();
  if(window_width < 300) {
    $("#myDiv").width(100);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work because the object is embedded.

Comment: What do you mean by embedded? On a embed tag?

Comment: Wrap the object tag in the above `div`

Answer (score 1):

Percentage will make your content to be responsive in smaller screens while resizing the window, while for example `500px` will always maintain that same value even though you resize the screen, unless you use media queries. **[Here's a example](http://jsfiddle.net/txeuj5ot/)**, Resize the window where the images are on this link to see it work.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="responsiveWidth">
        ...Responsive Image...
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0d/0b/7d/0d0b7db51cc6665c0943dc0759f88fa6.jpg" width="500">
    </div>

    <div class="staticWidth">
        ...Static Image...
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0d/0b/7d/0d0b7db51cc6665c0943dc0759f88fa6.jpg" width="500">
    </div>

</div>
```

and your CSS:

```
.staticWidth {
    width:500px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.responsiveWidth {
    width:100%;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.responsiveWidth img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: OK, **But how would it look if I used Javascript?**

Comment: There's no need or reason why you should do this using Javascript while you can simply do it with CSS. CSS is the right way to go

Comment: **If I add more stuff to the webpage, the footer(object) will get bigger. I don't want that to happen. I want it to resize on window resize.**

Comment: No need for the **bold text**. If you provide us a live example or a Jsfiddle file of what's happening and what you're trying to accomplish would be much easier to help. We are responding in demand of your needs on what you asked in your question, and not what you see from your part, in this case your live example. This will be an endless discussion to psychically understand what you are trying to create on your side.